# Using a variable outside the indentation

Tags: indentation

[image: indentation picture]

Hi my friends, I want to ask a question. I assigned a variable name num inside the first indentation, then used it at the third indentation, and it worked. What is the logic of it? As I know that you can only use a variable just only inside your indentation. Is that possible to use it in other indentations?

Answer (score 0):

In Python variables are declared within a block. Blocks are modules, function bodies and class definitions. If you declare something within a block, you may not use it outside of that block. Blocks can contain other blocks.

Example:

```
bar = 0 # if you declare a variable within a module, but outside of a function

def foo(): # you can use the variable anywhere within the module.
    print(bar) # even in functions. Since it is within the block of the module


def x():    # If you define a function x
    y = 0   # and the vars y and z within function x
    z = 45  
    if y == 0: # you may use y and z anywhere within x
        print(z)

print(y)    # but you cannot use y or z outside of the function.
            # Since it is outside of the block of the function
```